# Trace of matrix : cannot establish similarity invariant

Tags: matrices

The similarity invariance for a trace is:

$$
\text{Tr}(B)=\text{Tr}(P^{-1}BP)
$$

Suppose the following matrix B
$$
B=\pmatrix{
a & b \\
c & d
}
$$

The trace of $B$, that is $\text{Tr}(B)=a+d$.

I apply a transformation such that $D=P^{-1}BP$ is now diagonal.

$$
D=P^{-1}\pmatrix{
a & b \\
c & d
}P=\pmatrix{
\frac{1}{2}\left( a-\sqrt{4bc+(a-d)^2}+d \right) & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{2}\left( a+\sqrt{4bc+(a-d)^2}+d \right)
}
$$

The trace of $D$ is therefore $\frac{1}{2}\left( a-\sqrt{4bc+(a-d)^2}+d \right)+ \frac{1}{2}\left( a+\sqrt{4bc+(a-d)^2}+d \right)$

Thus, $\text{Tr}(B)\neq \text{Tr}(P^{-1}BP))$.

I am probably misunderstanding something but its been bugging me for a while.

---

Edit:

trying with a actual diagonalizable matrix:

$$
A=\pmatrix{
-1 & 3 & -1\\
-3 & 5 & -1\\
-3 & 3 &1
}
$$

The trace is $-1+5+1=5$.

Diagonalized is:

$$
D=\pmatrix{
2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
}
$$

and its trace is $2+2+1=5$

All good.

Comment: Not every 2 by 2 matrix is diagonalizable. The transformation you describe cannot exist. What is $P$ if $B=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: Under assumption that $A$ is diagonalizable:  replace $e$ with $d$ (it seems there is a typo, maybe also other mistake) and simplify. The square roots disappear and you get $a+d.$

Comment: @Nightgap Thanks, I'll edit the answer. Any idea why Mathematica returns eigenvalues for it?

Comment: @user376343 edited to remove errors.

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay Well, if the matrix is diagonalizable it has the mentioned eigenvalues. However, it might be that $4bc+(a-d)^2=0$. Then the two eigenvalues you gave are actually only one and the eigenspace to this eigenvalue might be one dimensional.

Comment: Since you edited your post and removed $e$, the last equation (before your edit line) is now false.

Comment: Amazing. You are proving that $\text{Tr}(B)= \text{Tr}(P^{-1}BP))$ (fifth sentence) and fail to see it !

Comment: @YvesDaoust ohhh! I see it now... oups.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments the formula can only be true if $B$ is diagonalizable. In this case it is correct and we have 
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{tr}(D)&=\frac12(a-\sqrt{4bc+(a-d)^2}+d)+\frac12(a+\sqrt{4bc+(a-d)^2}+d)\\
&=a+d-\frac12\sqrt{4bc+(a-d)^2}+\frac12\sqrt{4bc+(a-d)^2}\\
&=a+d.
\end{align*}